# Difference between attribute with and without android: in style

Tags: android, attributes, styles

I generate project with Navigation Drawer in Android Studio. And this is generated style.xml for api > 21:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I do not find any information in internet why some attribute with android: prefix and some without? Can You explain what is difference?

Thanks

Comment: *I do not find any information in internet why some attribute with android: prefix and some without?* seriously? the ones with namespace are from "original" android API and the ones without namespace are from the library ... obviously because were added after minimal version of API which is supported by library

Comment: for example [android:windowActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionBar) was added in API 11 but appcompat is supported on devices with API >= 7 .... so it has to be "emulated" some how(by creating new attribute)

Comment: windowNoTitle is in R.attr since API level 1 (not from lib) and windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds - API level 21. I correctly understand that if I want to use native attr I add prefix else not? For example, If there was an attribute like windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds in the support library then we use them for API < 21 without prefix (from lib) and for API >= 21 with prefix?